# CrudRepository return null

Tags: java, spring, crud-repository

I can't find where is a problem. I'm searching inside DB the user by Username and Password. But it return null.

This is my Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface UserCrudRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Integer>{

List<User> findByUsernameAndPassword(String username, String password);}
```

This is my Service:

```
@Service
public class UserService {
@Autowired
private UserCrudRepository crudRepo;


public List<User> findByUsernameAndByPassword(String username, String password){
//List<UserModel> ut=null;
//ut= crudRepo.findByUsernameAndPassword(username, password);
return crudRepo.findByUsernameAndPassword(username, password);
}
```

When I debug my app, I see that inside "findByUsernameAndPassword(username, password);"  the informations that user wrote are present, but the method retur null.

What's wrong here?

Comment: Is the result null or an empty List? is your database case sensitive? ("User1" vs "user1")
Reposiory returns List<User>, in the commented out part I see List<UserModel>...

Comment: Isn't everything interesting to this question happening inside `crudRepo.findByUsernameAndPassword`?

Comment: inside crudRepo.findByUsernameAndPassword() there is only Spring magic

Comment: @user3075118 return null. The DB is case sensitive, so I wrote all variables like in db

Comment: Maybe a silly question, but I guess you have encoded passwords in your DB, did you encode it also before calling `crudRepo.findByUsernameAndPassword(username, password)`?

Comment: set
logging.level.root = DEBUG 
in your application.properties and see if you can find an answer in the log

Comment: @JoãoDias nope, I don't encode the password before call this method

Comment: Do you mean you have plain text passwords in your database?

Comment: @JoãoDias nop, the password text it's like: "$2a$10$pBwsEsA8LGfK3VcRt4AJPeyq3uMaeA..."

Comment: Then it is encoded and you need to encode it before calling `crudRepo.findByUsernameAndPassword(username, password)`.

Comment: @JoãoDias even if he encodes the password before calling the method, there's a chance he'll not get the desired result, matching passwords must be done with PasswordEncoder and not manually. Change the code to get the user by username and call PasswordEncoder match function to check for the password equality

Comment: @b.GHILAS, that is true. I am writing a more complete answer including that very important detail

Answer (score 2):

Since you have encrypted passwords the best way to do this is by searching for the user only by `username` and then use `BCryptPasswordEncoder` to match your plain text `password` with the encoded version you have in the database. You could get a `BCryptPasswordEncoder` in your Service as follows:

```java
@Service
public class UserService {
  @Autowired
  private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncode;

  @Autowired
  private UserCrudRepository crudRepo;

  public List<User> findByUsernameAndByPassword(String username, String password){
    List<User> users = crudRepo.findByUsername(username);
    for (user : users) {
       if (bCryptPasswordEncoder.matches(password, user.getPassword())) {
          // passwords match
       }
    }
  }
}
```

You also need to have a configuration file where you ask for a `BCryptPasswordEncoder` to be created:

```java
public class SecurityConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

And you need to adapt your repository:

```java
@Repository
public interface UserCrudRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Integer>{
  List<User> findByUsername(String username);
}
```

I assume that you are using this as a form os authentication, so you might consider taking a look at `UserDetailsService` interface (https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetailsService.html) if you are not using it already.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to write a **query** to fetch the user detail in the **UserCrudRepository**.

```
@Query("SELECT u FROM User u WHERE lower(u.username) LIKE %?1% AND " +
      "lower(u.password) LIKE %?2%")
List<User> findByUsernameAndPassword(String username, String password);
```